# Export Sql server data to Excel by using Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export the SQL server data to the excel file with using the sql query. But i am getting error

`OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".`

The Query which i am using

```
select * from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\share\Test1.xlsx;HDR=YES','SELECT id FROM [Sheet1$]') SELECT id FROM Table
```

I have also enabled

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE


 EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'AllowInProcess', 0 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'DynamicParameters', 0
GO
```

I have also shared my folder with full permissions.
I have Given the Excel file same headers with the table name
But Same Error

Answer (score 0):

The connection you are using is wrong: it is the JET driver which

- is for reading/writing flat files of various types
- is pointing to a file called c:\share\test1.xlsx
- is obsolete, and has been replaced by the ACE drivers.

You need to re-write your code. [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306125&sd=tech) gives a good idea on how to do it. One bit you must NOT miss out, and should do first, is the para titled **Referencing the ADO object library**.

You may well have a whole load of questions about things the code is doing (for instance, what is INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI? and a load more), so many that I'm not going to answer them because I would have to write a chapter of a book to and I don't know whether you would ask any of them. I suggest that you read the article, try the code, and then post individual questions in invividual posts here.

Once clue; this bit of code:

```
'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=(local);INITIAL CATALOG=pubs;"
```

...is specifying the database server and the name of the database. Replace the (local) with the name of the database server if it's not your local machine. The pubs name is the name of the database. Replace with your database.

Also, this bit:

```
' Extract the required records.
.Open "SELECT * FROM Authors"
```

Here, "SELECT * from Authors" is the SQL which defines the data the query will return. You need to replace this with the SQL which will get the data you want from your database. Again, a rather large subject.